# How do you use Greek letters in pages, 5.5.2?

Tags: mac

Need to use some Greek letters using pages, 5.5.2?

Comment: occasional? always?, sometimes? easy switchable on/off ?

Answer (score 3):

Open the Character Viewer and drag the letters from there in to your document.

[image: Greek]

If you have to use it more frequently you can set it up bit automated, in the syst pref- Keyboard- Text. Then assign a Greek letter to some word like when you type Beta it would be replaced with Greek β.

Answer (score 1):

In System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources, add one of the Greek Input Sources.

[image: System Prefs]
You can then select that input source from the menulet that appears in the right hand end of the menu bar.

You'll have to work out which letters on your keyboard add which Greek characters, but you can use the Keyboard Viewer (a menu item in the menulet) to choose and type the chars.

[image: menulet]

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp2214/mac

Answer (score 0):

Use http://www.unicodeit.net

You can also turn it into a Service, so just use LaTeX notation (like \alpha for α), highlight, and use some unique keybinding (I use shift-opt-cmd-u) and it will convert to the unicode character.  Works across the system.

Answer (score -1):

You can always install the Greek alphabet on your Mac, the same way as you'd install any other language.

Comment: You don't install alphabets, nor languages. Most fonts will already contain the Greek alphabet characters: you just have to access them. MacOS is capable of operating in any language by default: you just have to change its Keyboard Input Source and other Language settings in System Prefs.

Comment: So, you're correcting me for using the word "alphabet" ? Or the word "install" ? You say "change its Keyboard Input Source" when you really mean press the + symbol to add another "Input Source" . And that's why I don't contribute in any forums and that's also why the only people that do actually say (or should I say "type"? or should I TYPE "type"?) anything on the Internet are usually unable to read through the function of the discourse itself like yourself. The guy wanted to type in Greek. I'm Greek. I type in Greek. Καλά μυαλά παλτό (translate that)

Comment: I don't consider myself to be as strict as some here, but a certain amount of accuracy is required in any answer. If you meant "change the input source", then "install an alphabet" is a long way off. If you want to modify your answer, then please do so. 
My translation software gives "good coat minds", but I'm guessing I should look for greater accuracy? ;-)
All the best

Comment: You too buddy 